# How to choose the Data Stucture

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a table of data like this.

[image: table of data]

I want to perform numerous operations on it like

- How many times was PLAY 'no' when it was sunny
- How many times was WINDY 'true' when PLAY was 'yes'

What data structure should I use?
right now I have simple array which is coming out to be one heck of a task to control.

```
string[,] trainingData = new string[noOfRecords,5];
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("input.txt"))
        {
            int i =0;
            string text = "";
            while ((text = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] bits = text.Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < noOfColumnsOfData; j++)
                {
                    trainingData[i, j] = bits[j];
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How 'bout using `IEnumerable` then you can use `LinQ` to perform conditional select on it?

Comment: I was looking on simpler lines e.g ArrayList or Generics

Comment: In my opinion, you should create a class for your table, and use table column as its properties. Each row in your table will correspond to an instance of that class. Then put those object into a list. Now you can easily perform conditional select on that list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To widen @Doan cuong's anwer,
I would use an enumarable list of objects.
each object can be calle: Record and the collection can be called Table.
(Table is IEnumarable).

Here is a simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            int count1 = table.records.Where(r => r.Play == false && r.Outlook.ToLower() == "sunny").Count();
        }

        public class Record
        {
            public bool Play;
            public string Outlook;
        }


        public class Table
        {
            //This should be private and Table should be IEnumarable
            public List<Record> records = new List<Record>(); 

        }
```

Comment: uhmm, there's a little error in your code, `==` instead of `=` :D

Comment: Thanks, I've written a compiled example instead

Answer (score 1):

this is a highly uncomfortable question because it's about opinion more then a valid programing question. a lot of programmers would say this or that. for the table you are showing there is no problem using array as you did for simple queries as you mentioned. for more complex data and queries i would suggest you'll take the time and effort to study [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class and write the values to properties. I.e.:

```
public class Weather
{
 public string Outlook {get;set;}
 ...
}
```

And then store them into a `List<Weather>` collection (during your loop). Like already said, you can run `LINQ` queries on it. The internet is full of example how to use `LINQ`.